# How to nest all views into one view, which is placed vertically central?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Here's my **MainActivity.xml** where  I'm using `LinearLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#ffe6cc"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.zorgan.app.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="#333"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="116dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/front"
        android:contentDescription="@string/front_desc" />

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="496dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How would I nest these 3 views into one view, so they all sit vertically central?

Comment: what you need? you need to centre the inner three views?

Comment: Yes. At the moment they're all sitting at the top of the screen (on top of each other), i'd like for them to be on top of each other in the centre of the screen.

Comment: it is unclear what are you are asking. Please be specific about your problem, add screenshot if possible.

Comment: set android:gravity in LinearLayout

Comment: Just wrap the LinearLayour with height wrap_content inside RelativeLayout or FrameLayout with gravity center_vertical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To vertically center the child views, give `android:gravity="center_vertical"` to the parent view. In your case, for the LinearLayout.

Comment: Happy coding. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

here try this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#ffe6cc"

    android:gravity="center"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.zorgan.app.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="#333"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="116dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/front"
        android:contentDescription="@string/front_desc" />

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="496dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

in this `android:gravity="center"` is the key parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#ffe6cc"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="#333"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="116dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/front"
    android:contentDescription="front_desc" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

It is tested and working.

Comment: Copycat :P Its the same as @V-rund 's answer.

Comment: @ Shadow hope you are not blind. :).. Have some cookies.